# Parse the Anchor tags and the content using NSXMLParse

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, nsxmlparser, xmlnode

I want to parse the html tags inside the "comparison" node

```
<comparison>
    <a href="/cgi-bin/amazon.cgi?B0050AMJYU">Amazon.com</a>
    ($34.36) |
    <a href="/cgi-bin/walmart.cgi?16904483">Walmart.com</a>
    ($34.36) |
    <a href="/cgi-bin/rakuten.cgi?219782579">Rakuten.com</a>
    ($34.36) |
    <a href="/cgi-bin/bestbuy1.cgi?mp1307815397">BestBuy.com</a>
    ($34.36)
</comparison>
```

The output I am getting is:

```
 BestBuy.com ($34.36)
```

The expected output:

```
Amazon.com ($34.36)  
Walmart.com ($34.36) 
Rakuten.com ($34.36)  
BestBuy.com ($34.36)
```

But I want to display all the four items.

**CODE**

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    currentElementValue = [NSMutableString string];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        dealsListObj = [[DealsParsingObjects alloc] init];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"short_title"]) {
        dealsListObj.itemTitle = currentElementValue;
        currentElementValue = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"final_price"]) {
        dealsListObj.price = currentElementValue;
        currentElementValue = nil;
    }
    //Detail view
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"merchant"]) {
        dealsListObj.itemMerchant = currentElementValue;
        currentElementValue = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"getdeal"]) {
        dealsListObj.itemGetDeal = currentElementValue;
        currentElementValue = nil;
    }
    //comparison
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"comparison"]) {
        dealsListObj.comparison = currentElementValue;
        currentElementValue = nil;

    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        [resultArray addObject:dealsListObj];
        [dealsListObj release];
        dealsListObj = nil;
        currentElementValue = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your parsing code?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a `DealsParsingObjects` class with an `NSMutableArray` called `commentsArray`. You instantiate that array, when the parsing begins reading the `<comparison>` element.

But when the parser has read a `<comparison>` element, you assign the value to a property called `comparison`; it doesn't get added to the array. Being an default `NSString` property (assumption on my part), it simply gets reassigned each time the parser is done reading a `<comparison>` element.

**Edit:**

`parser:didStartElement:...` is called every time a new element is read. This also holds for the `<a>` tags. In that method you reset `currentElementValue`. So for each `<a>` the value is basically reset to an empty string. Only the last read value remains, which is the value of the last `<a>` tag plus the trailing text.

Comment: I removed that part and that was not used.